How do I deploy a Express Socket Io server?
I need to deploy a backend node expressjs server using socket io via a web service so that I can connect it to my frontend (nextjs).
I need the web service to be free - heroku shut down and services like render.com which although does work well, shuts down if there is no active fecthing and then when it does get fetched, the server takes like 1 - 2m to restart back on which i do not want. Is there any solutions to do this? any better web deployment services?
